lxml won't validate valid URI
I'm attempting to run an xslt with the following line.
<xsl:include href="http://www.loc.gov/marcxml/xslt/MARC21slimUtils.xsl"/>

The following error is thrown
lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Cannot resolve URI https://www.loc.gov/marcxml/xslt/MARC21slimUtils.xsl

The URI is valid and works from my browser.  Why would it not resolve?

Could you please provide the code that you are using.

Are other https URIs resolved?

Did you get that right? Your XSLT code contains an http URI, and the error message refers to an https URI?

I have had some problems with  HTTPS access with xsltproc or lxml, with lxml I could solve them by using a resolver https://lxml.de/resolvers.html#uri-resolvers that delegates HTTP(S) access to urllib3.

I've had similar problems in the past with access to data which had previously been published with http and later switched to https. Some HTTP(S) libraries are not great at following HTTP redirects across protocols or using the HSTS mechanism. I would just change your xsl:include to load the https URL in the first place and see if that helps. If it doesn't, perhaps it's a certification problem (i.e. a lack of trust on the part of your HTTP client library)?

This question is 13 years old, but I think it is still true that lxml cannot parse directly from an HTTPS URL: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7882673/407651. Most likely because libxml2 does not support HTTPS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57328510/407651.

The comment above should be in much greater evidence.
I have been working a full day to discover that information.
No way to log in to the 'lxlm' package issue tracker to ask to help user avoid the problem.
The issue is particularly heavy when the XML contains 'include' or 'import' directives referencing an 'http' resource that actually is redirected to an 'https' source.
@scoder( gh@behnel.de ): please add "and not https" beside "http" in the help messages of etree.parse()
